# Javascript function to append table with cells containing input field and value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, append

I created a working function that appends a table with cells/rows and then populates those cells with data from an array. The problem is now I need to change it so that the generated cells contain an `input` field where the `value=` is the array data.

Here is an example of the closest I have been able to come: http://jsfiddle.net/JEAkX/3/

at one point I tried changing to `cell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' size='1'>"+ subset[i++] +"</input>"` but it just put the data outside of the input text area.

`subset[i++]` creates the correct output but I cant seem to get it inside a field value.

Here is the function **before** I edited it for an input field:

```
function appendTable(id)
{
    var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var i = 0;
    for (var r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        var row = tbody.insertRow(r);
        for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell(c);
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(subset[i++]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All these answers here work, thanks guys! Giving it @JeanK for being first.

Comment: +1 for using/introducing jsfiddle (for people unfamiliar with it. e.g. myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
cell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' size='1'>"+ subset[i++] +"</input>"
```

Try to do this:

```
cell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' size='1' value='" + subset[i++] + "'/>"
```

Using the value property of the input, this way it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I think I tried this once but must have messed up a `"` somewhere and not double checked when it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, you need to add the text to the input value like:

```
cell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' size='1' value='" + subset[i++] + "' />";
```

and your subset needs to be populated with some values.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
 value=''+subset[i++]
```

instead of

```
value='subset[i++]'
```

So your new function should read like :

```
function appendTable(id)
{
    var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var i = 0;
    for (var r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        var row = tbody.insertRow(r);
        for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell(c);
            cell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' size='1' value=''+subset[i++] />"
        }
    }
}
```